# How to change the start page of a UWP after a button click

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have a UWP application where I need to change the start page of the application only after the user clicking a button on the third page.

I have tried the following code. The below code helps me navigate to the name page directly skipping the welcome page once the application is opened the second time but I want this to function only after the user clicking a button in the third page.

```
var roamingSettings = ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings;
                    if (roamingSettings.Values.ContainsKey("NotFirstTimeLaunch"))
                    {
                        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(Name), e.Arguments);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        roamingSettings.Values["NotFirstTimeLaunch"] = true;
                        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(WelcomePage), e.Arguments);
                    }
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to move this line to your button click event handler:

```
roamingSettings.Values["NotFirstTimeLaunch"] = true;
```